# trying to dynamically create bot using botUI

Tags: bots

i have array named ***content***

content=[[{content:'gffdhdfhdfhdf'}],[{content:'gffdhdfhdfhdf'}],[{content:'gffdhdfhdfhdf'}],[{content:'gffdhdfhdfhdf'}]];

in botUI

```
 botui.message.add({
        content: 'Hello World from bot!'
      }).then(function () { // wait till previous message has been shown.

        botui.message.add({
          delay: 1000,
          human: true,
          content: 'Hello World from human!'
        });
      });
```

i want to pass content from my array ***content*** in  botui.message.add
with ***then*** means pass second object of ***content*** object in ***first then*** then third  object inside of ***first then*** and so on and and when last then with last object have ***then*** but with different condition.

*like:*

```
botui.message.add({
            content: content[0]
          }).then(function () { // wait till previous message has been shown.

            botui.message.add({
              delay: 1000,
              human: true,
              content: content[1]
            }).then(function () { // wait till previous message has been shown.

            botui.message.add({
              delay: 1000,
              human: true,
              content: content[n]
            });
          });
          });
```

*is this possible ?*

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, but create the array above 
like so:

```js
var content =['hello there','Nice to meet you']
```